# Date conversion to timestamp in EPOCH

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to convert date to day minus 1 12:00 AM (epoch time) in spark

```
val dateInformat=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")
val batchpartitiondate= LocalDate.parse("10-14-2022",dateInformat)
batchpartitiondate: javatimelocalDate=2022-10-14

batchpartitiondate should be converted to  epochtime(1665619200)
```

Date for example:

InputDate in spark submit argument is 12-15-2022

I need the output as epoch time (1665705600) i.e in GMT:Friday,October 14,12:00:00AM

if i give input as 12-14-2022 it should give the output as epoch time (1665619200) i.e in GMT:Thursday,October 13,12:00:00AM

Comment: do you have any timezone or it's an UTC time ?

Comment: It's UTC time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this achieve what you are looking to do?

```scala
    val dateInFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")
    val batchPartitionDate = LocalDate.parse("10-14-2022", dateInformat)
    val alteredDateTime = batchPartitionDate.minusDays(1).atStartOfDay()

    // current zone
    {
      val zone = ZoneId.systemDefault()
      val instant = alteredDateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant
      val epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli
    }
    
    // UTC
    // Or you can specify the appropriate timezone insteasd of UTC
    {
      val zone = ZoneOffset.UTC
      val instant = alteredDateTime.toInstant(zone)
      val epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli
    }
```

Comment: I think `atStartOfDay` should be called after `atZone(zone)`, not before

Comment: I dont think it would matter, because I believe its going to set it to the start of the day of whatever zone you put. This would be a different story if you had a ZonedDateTime in the first place, and then adjusted it to a new zone. I could be wrong, but thats my intuition.